# How to add internal public repository to satis.json?

Tags: composer-php

Need some help in understanding a scenario with satis.json , My question is we have already a package named as ""xamin/handlebars.php" used in our project as a composer dependency and recently this package is abandoned, so we have planned to fork the repository to our internal github and added patches to it. Now it's time to tell my satis.json to use the latest version from our github internal repo.

So I have updated repositories section as

```
"repositories": [
        {"name": "xamin/handlebars.php",
         "type": "git",
          "url": "git@github.corp.test.com:BE/XaminProject-handlebars.php.git"}
    ],
```

and I just kept as it is in require section :

```
"require": {
        "xamin/handlebars.php": "0.10.5",
}
```

Now if I try to do composer update from my local dev:

It says :

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning: Accessing satis-new.test.com over http which is an insecure protocol.
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - The requested package xamin/handlebars.php ^0.10.5 exists as xamin/handlebars.php[v0.10.4, v0.10.0, v0.10.1, v0.10.2, v0.10.3] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Comment: I’d you open Satis’ web UI and search for the package, does version `0.10.5` show up?;

Comment: @Adam Thanks, i later realized that new bump of package version that i have created internally which is not in satis repo.